# Bootstrap Tags in dynamic knockout accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I´m having this knockout-loop:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'task-template', foreach: ¨Tasks, afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }"></div>   

     <script type="text/html" id="task-template">
         <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}, click: $root.SelectedTask" class="group">
             <h3><b><span data-bind="text: TaskId"></span>: <input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName"/></b></h3>
             <p>
                 <label for="Description" >Description:</label><textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>

                 <!-- HERE I want to put the Tags for the current task -->

             </p> 
         </div>
    </script>
```

where 
    self.Tasks() = ko.observableArray(); 
in my ViewModel, populated like this:

self.Tasks().push(new Task(data);  where

```
Task = function( data) { 
var self=this;
self.TaskId = ko.observable(data.TaskId);
self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
self.TaskTags = ko.observableArray();
}
```

self.TaskTags is then populated later with an array of tags collected from the database and filtered with TaskId.

Outside the knockout-loop, the following markup works:

```
   <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="Pisa, Rome" name="hiddenTagList">
```

with

```
$(function () {
                $(".tagsManager").tagsManager({
                    prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Oslo"],
                    //prefilled: viewModel.Tags().TagName,
                    CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
                    preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
                    typeahead: true,
                    typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
                    typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "Oslo", "New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
                    delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
                    backspace: [8],
                    blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
                    blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
                    hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
                });
            });
```

However the "class" must be dynamical in my loop. I reckon I can achieve this with something like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Tags" data-bind="attr: {'class': 'tagsManager' + SceneId}"  />
```

The question is how do I bind *tagsManager* to these dynamic elements?

Also: For each Task I have a self.TaskTags = ko.observableArray(/* loaded from database */);

and instead of looping over the static list of nice cities I´d like to present the tags attached to the actual task(s).

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set classes on elements, use the `css` binding with an observable whose value is the class (or list of classes) to add to whatever is already statically specified as the element's class.

To bind `tagsManager` to elements as you create them, create a custom binding type:

```
ko.bindinghandlers.tagsManager={
  init: function(element) {
    $(element).tagsManager(
       ...
    );
  }
};
```

and then include `tagsManager` in the `data-bind` attribute for elements than need it.